# How to remove the duplicate in ag grid (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

How to remove the duplicate `assetCode` in ag grid.
instead the `PRN` and `PRN1` keep repeating

here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
ngOnInit() {
this.rowData.push(
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-18 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 1', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-19 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 2', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-20 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 3', 'assetCode': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1,
        'date': '2019-01-21 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 4', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-22 00:00:00'
      },
      {
        'code': 'Machine 5', 'assetCode': 'PRN 1', 'assetCount': 3,
        'date': '2019-01-23 00:00:00'
      },
    );

    this.rowData = this.rowData.filter((item: any) => {
      return format(item.date, 'YYYY') === param;
    });

    const newData: any = [];
    this.rowData.forEach((x: any) => {
      const existing = newData.find((y: any) => format(y.date, 'YYYY-MM') === format(x.date, 'YYYY-MM')
        && y.assetCode === x.assetCode && y.code === x.code);
      if (existing) {
        console.log(existing);
        existing.assetCount += existing.assetCount;
      } else {
        newData.push(x);
        this.rowData = newData;
      }
    });

    this.columnDefs.push(
      {
        'headerName': 'Style/Machine',
        'field': 'code',
        'pinned': 'left',
        'lockPosition': true
      }
    );

    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      const record = {
        'headerName': this.monthNames[i].monthName,
        'children': [
          {
            'headerName': 'Total', 'columnGroupShow': 'closed', 'field': 'total'
          }
        ]
      };

      this.rowData.forEach((key: any) => {
        if (this.monthNames[i].monthName === format(key.date, 'MMMM')) {
          record.children.push(
            {
              'headerName': key.assetCode, 'columnGroupShow': 'open', 'field': 'assetCount'
            }
          );
        }
      });
      this.columnDefs.push(record);
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate in what basis?

Comment: @AdritaSharma the ```assetCode```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zw5zat?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
  result = [];
  constructor() {
    this.result = this.GetDistinctValues(this.data, "assetCode");
  }

 GetDistinctValues(Source: Array<any>, FilterKey: string = null): Array<any> {

   let DistinctArray = [];
    Source.forEach(e => {
      if (FilterKey !== null && FilterKey !== undefined && FilterKey !== "") {
        if (
          DistinctArray.filter(DE => DE[FilterKey] === e[FilterKey]).length <= 0
        )
          DistinctArray.push(e);
      } else {
        if (DistinctArray.indexOf(e) === -1) DistinctArray.push(e);
      }
    });

    return DistinctArray;
  }
```

Comment: is there other possible way to do it? without using the ```try catch```?

Comment: You can remove the try catch block. Check the modified demo

Answer (score 0):

```js
let rowDataList=[{'code':'Machine 1','assetCode':'PRN','assetCount':1,'date':'2019-01-18 00:00:00'},{'code':'Machine 1','assetCode':'PRN','assetCount':1,'date':'2019-01-19 00:00:00'},{'code':'Machine 2','assetCode':'PRN 1','assetCount':3,'date':'2019-01-20 00:00:00'},{'code':'Machine 3','assetCode':'PRN','assetCount':1,'date':'2019-01-21 00:00:00'},{'code':'Machine 4','assetCode':'PRN 1','assetCount':3,'date':'2019-01-22 00:00:00'},{'code':'Machine 5','assetCode':'PRN 1','assetCount':3,'date':'2019-01-23 00:00:00'}];

let rowData = Object.values(rowDataList.reduce((acc,c)=>(acc[c.assetCode]=c,acc),{}));
console.log(rowData);
```